# Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:2181: unexpected error Permission denied

Tags: docker, windows-10, apache-zookeeper

Just installed *Docker Desktop Community* but cannot start zookeeper.

```
C:\kafka>docker run --rm -d --name zookeeper --network app-tier -p 2181:2181 -p 3888:3888 zookeeper:latest
Unable to find image 'zookeeper:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/zookeeper
8e402f1a9c57: Pull complete
4866c822999c: Pull complete
205f26e90552: Pull complete
99243f6904c1: Pull complete
c6ac2a949410: Pull complete
7c9e37572768: Pull complete
637f41838913: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:7eb73b4f16688bdd6c6594ea3aacbaf31dacc33f7a8ab0d52a4fdc08bc4f919a
Status: Downloaded newer image for zookeeper:latest
1d96e4605efcd0836b9121be75c381195547014bb9d42ea4716c8a1b60068903
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint zookeeper (48149ba74f7230bef95a5c98ab968498d0f965bede97ada98115384906c06300): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:2181: unexpected error Permission denied.
```

**Docker version**

- Version 2.0.0.3 (31259)
- Channel stable
- Build 8858db3
- Engine 18.09.2

**Windows version**

- Windows 10 version: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.348]

**Networks**

```
C:\Proyectos\kafka>docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
5ed898201a6d        app-tier            bridge              local
f0bd501b76fa        bridge              bridge              local
5c822b39b283        host                host                local
eb54047d3dc8        none                null                local
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: After some minutes in standby mode, The same command in docker has worked. Not sure why it fails sometimes. An issue is registered for this in https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1038

Answer (score 6):

I ran across this same issue after having used Zookeeper on port 2181 for months. I couldn't figure out why it wouldn't bind to port 2181 as I had ran `netstat -aon | findstr '2181'` as admin and would get back no results. I eventually came to the conclusion that the port was in fact in use by some process even though it wasn't listed. The solution that I found to still use port 2181 (this was critical for my application):

Start Windows in Safe Mode with Networking

In powershell/cmd run the command `netsh int ipv4 add excludedportrange protocol=tcp startport=2181 numberofports=1` This will reserve the port 2181 so when you boot back into normal windows mode no application will steal the port before you can use it.

Boot into regular windows and start Zookeeper. With this there will be no bind issues!

Comment: Thanks @cmpickle! After trying all of these: restarting docker, resetting docker, restarting my computer, disabling fast boot based on this comment https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1038#issuecomment-458440399, reinstalling docker. I was almost about to give up. Running the netsh command did the trick!

Comment: If you dont mind changing the port just wire the port to something else external "-p 28017:2181", that should do that trick as well :)

Comment: @Lagoni yes, you definitely can do that. For my specific scenario my team all are using the same port and the port is defined in several install scripts and so I wasn't able to make my whole team change ports just because it wasn't working on my machine. :)